# ¿Cómo usar TO_CHAR en mi @Query usando JPA en Java?

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, jpa, microservices

Tengo la siguiente entidad, el campo **HORA_INICIAL** en la base de datos es de tipo TIMESTAMP, y yo lo mapie como tipo Date

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name= "EJECUCION")
    public class EjecucionEntity{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "COMENTARIO")
    private comentario 
    
    @Column(name = "HORA_INICIAL")
    private Date horaInicial;
    
    @Column(name = "FECHA_PROCESAMIENTO")
    private Date fechaProcesamiento;
    
    }
```

y esta es mi clase Repository y funciona bien

```
public interface EjecucionRepository extends JpaRepository<EjecucionEntity, Integer>{

  @Query(value = "SELECT E.ID, E.COMENTARIO, E.HORA_INICIAL, E.FECHA_PROCESAMIENTO FROM EJECUCION 
         E", nativeQuery = true)
  List<EjecucionEntity> consulta();
    
}
```

lo que quiero hacer es que la información que me regresa el campo **HORA_INICIAL** sea en este formato **'HH24:MI'**, ya que por Default lo muestra asi:  **2000-01-01 17:50:00.0** y entonces estoy tratando de usar el `TO_CHAR` para darle ese formato, lo aplique en el SQLDeveloper y lo muestra bien, pero a la hora de quererlo agregar en mi query del Repository me marca error

```
public interface EjecucionRepository extends JpaRepository<EjecucionEntity, Integer>{
        @Query(value = "SELECT E.ID, E.COMENTARIO, TO_CHAR(E.HORA_INICIAL, 'HH24:MI'), 
              E.FECHA_PROCESAMIENTO FROM EJECUCION E")
        List<EjecucionEntity> consulta();
    
    }
```

marca el error:

> SQL ERROR: 17006, SQLSTATE: 99999, NOMBRE DE COLUMNA NO VALIDO

estoy aplicando mal el TO_CHAR? o como mas puedo darle ese formato al campo

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que te está pidiendo es que le pongas un alias a la consulta, concretamente a la columna TO_CHAR(E.HORA_INICIAL, 'HH24:MI'), tal que así:

```
public interface EjecucionRepository extends JpaRepository<EjecucionEntity, Integer>{
        @Query(value = "SELECT E.ID, E.COMENTARIO, TO_CHAR(E.HORA_INICIAL, 'HH24:MI') HORA_INICIAL, 
              E.FECHA_PROCESAMIENTO FROM EJECUCION E")
        List<EjecucionEntity> consulta();
    
    }
```

Comment: ES CORRECTO, ASI ME FUNCIONÓ, LE PUSE AS HORA_INICIAL Y LISTO, GRACIAS

Answer (score 2):

En Spring Data JPA, la anotación `@Query` sirve para hacer consultas en el lenguaje de programación de JPA, JPQL. Para hacer consultas en SQL debes agregar la opción `nativeQuery`.

Tu consulta quedaría así:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT E.ID, E.COMENTARIO, TO_CHAR(E.HORA_INICIAL, 'HH24:MI'), 
    E.FECHA_PROCESAMIENTO FROM EJECUCION E", nativeQuery = true)
List<EjecucionEntity> consulta();
```